# max-height image inside of grid with min-height should respect the grid's size rather than extending it

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a layout with 3 columns, 2 rows, using a grid whose `min-height` is `90vh`.

The left and right columns contain an image, which is supposed to be justified towards the center column, and it is supposed to be aligned vertically (it should not be enlarged if it is smaller than its cell). However, the image should not exceed the maximum width of its cell (`max-width: 100%`), and it should not exceed the maximum height of its cell (`max-height: 100%`); if it does, it should be downscaled.

The second row contains a caption. This caption should be anchored at the bottom of the grid, but no fixed height can be assumed.

The problem is that when using `min-height` instead of `height` for the grid, and `max-height` for the image, no downscaling of the images occurs. Instead, the image forces the grid cell to grow vertically.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 100px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  min-height: 90vh;
}

/* these are applied to img elements directly inside the grid */
.left, .right {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  align-self: center;
}
.left {
  justify-self: right;
}
.right {
  justify-self: left;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="left" src="https://i.imgur.com/2byCwGq.jpg"/>
  <div class="center">center column</div>
  <img class="right" src="https://i.imgur.com/tzPAOIo.jpg"/>

  <div>caption left</div>
  <div>caption center</div>
  <div>caption right</div>
</div>
```

**Note**: I am using `min-height` rather than `height` because the middle column may exceed `90vh`, and if I use `height`, the overflowing content from the grid overlaps the grid itself (which is undesirable).

Below is a demo page. When the viewport height is reduced, at some point the taller of the two images will be big enough such that its grid cell height is increased and the total grid height will exceed 90vh.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 100px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  min-height: 90vh;
  background-color: #077;
}

.left, .right {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  align-self: center;
}
.left {
  justify-self: right;
}
.right {
  justify-self: left;
}

.center {
  background-color: #770;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <img class="left" src="https://i.imgur.com/2byCwGq.jpg"/>
  <div class="center">center column</div>
  <img class="right" src="https://i.imgur.com/tzPAOIo.jpg"/>
  
  <div style="background-color: #700">caption left</div>
  <div style="background-color: #700">caption center</div>
  <div style="background-color: #700">caption right</div>
</div>

<hr/>
<p>after container</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if the stackoverflow inline preview handles viewport units correctly. If it does, you can immediately see that the images are not getting downscaled, so the grid's height definitely exceeds `90vh`. When the grid has `height` instead of `min-height`, it works, but the content after the grid container may overlap the grid container once it gets too small.

I have tried a bunch of different combinations with width/height, align-self, etc., but no luck.

How can I make it so that the img's `max-height: 100%` respects its parent grid's cell height?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a `max-height` property equal to `90vh` to `.left` and `.right` as well.

You can also use `object-fit` property to contain the image.

```css
.left, .right {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 90vh;
  align-self: center;
  object-fit: contain
}
```

Comment: 90vh on the images is not the same as 90vh on the grid because the grid also has a second row.